# extract Xpath for string in a div class

Tags: xpath

I have the below XPath

```
<div class="sic_cell {symbol : 'GGRM.JK'}">
    <a href="/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=GGRM.JK">Gudang Garam Tbk.</a>
</div>
```

I would like to extract `"GGRM.JK"`from the HTML.

```
//div[contains(@class, "symbol")]
```

return element not no text of `"GGRM.JK"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you are using python, try the following:

```
import lxml.html as lh
data = """[your html above]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(data)

#version 1
target = doc.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "symbol")]/@class')[0]    
print(target.split("'")[1])

#version 2
target2 = doc.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "symbol")]/a/@href')[0]
target2.split('=')[1]
```

In either case, the output should be

```
GGRM.JK
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to get the substing you want with xpath only, without postprocessing, is to use a functions `substring-after` and `substring-before`.

Here is an example, how to get 'GGRM.JK' from both class and href attributes.

```python
import lxml.html as lh

htmlText = """<div class="sic_cell {symbol : 'GGRM.JK'}">
    <a href="/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=GGRM.JK">Gudang Garam Tbk.</a>
</div>"""

htmlDom = lh.fromstring(htmlText)

fromHref = htmlDom.xpath('substring-after(//div/a/@href, "=")')
print(fromHref)

fromClass = htmlDom.xpath('substring-before(substring-after(//div/@class, ": \'"), "\'")')
print(fromClass)
```

Comment: `xpath(substring-after(string(//div/a/@href), '='))` return error. substring is not defined in python

Comment: What xml engine do you use in python? Give me more context.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I've put a complete example and explanation.